# How to test get/post(which takes param) API which is created inside Context and called in other component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I have created a function which fetches data from API and send a response of userDetail, which has been created in context. and function has been called in Dashboard component by importing context. And when user clicks button it render userData.

I am tried testing to check function has been called once or not, after click. but not able to achieve it.

**Context Page**
here userDataFunc is created .

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const Contx = createContext();

export class ConProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    userData: []
  };

  userDataFunc = async () => {
    await axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            userData: res.data
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        this.setState({
          userDataerror: err
        })
      );
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.coin);
    return (
      <Contx.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          userDataFunc: this.userDataFunc
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Contx.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Dashboard Component**
Here Function and userdata state has been imported from context

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Contx } from "../ContextApi";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const { userDataFunc, userData } = useContext(Contx);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "#151515" }}
      className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
    >
      <button data-testid="renderData" onClick={userDataFunc}>
        Render Data
      </button>
      <div
        style={{
          overflowY: "auto",
          margin: "4px",
          border: "2px solid",
          padding: "12px",
          height: "80vh"
        }}
        data-testid="tableData"
      >
        {userData.map((i) => {
          return (
            <h5 key={i.id} style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
              {i.name}
            </h5>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Dashboard Test File***

```
// import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import axiosMock from "axios";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import { Contx } from "../ContextApi";

jest.mock("axios");

it("Api Called", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <Contx>
      <Dashboard />
    </Contx>
  );

  const renderButton = getByTestId("userData");
  fireEvent.click(renderButton);
  expect(Dashboard.userDataFunc()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```